# How to get combination of related rows

Tags: php, mysql

I've a large table of articles, and want to get related articles based on a similarity of some kind - for example i've got 2 articles; The first article's title is "Article Part 1" and the second article is "Article Part 2".

What I want effectively is an output of the most likely matches for an article based on title either if its a variation of the current article or whether a continuation of the article or a modification.

Example:

```
 article_title  friendly_url   id
 Article 1      article-1      013
 Article 2      article-2      023
 Example 1      example-1      034
 Example 3      example-3      016
 Example 2      example-2      015
```

So I would ideally like a kind of string match based on the title so then, the "Article 1" related article(s) would be "Article 2" or "Example 3" related article(s) would be "Example 1" and "Example 2".

Note: The title can be more than 2 words and they may include special characters, for example, a title may be "How to: tutorial part 1" and then it will be related to "How to: tutorial part 2".

My idea is that I can use a MySQL query to perform this, but looking around PHP may have some better functions. The table is 1300+ articles, so making this manually by selecting from a list what article it will be related is not a viable solution.

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Normalize your database, it will make this kind of stuff much easier. By this I mean make an own row where you write the id of the linked articles. Like:

```
article_group  article_title  friendly_url   id
0              Article 1      article-1      013
0              Article 2      article-2      023
1              Example 1      example-1      034
1              Example 3      example-3      016
1              Example 2      example-2      015
```

Then you can have an own table for the name of each article group as well and other info on it. If the title is always the same, but it just have a number that differs them, then you can put that into the group and just keep the number in the above table, and is there any point to the friendly_url then? The latter questions are up to you though.

Comment: The problem here is that this would be made manually, or not? And doing that manually in a 1300+ database (link each article to its related article(s)) would take me forever.

Comment: That sucks, sounds like someone designed it poorly then. Hmm, but yeah, the database should be normalized if this is a normal occurrence. In any case, sorry, I'm not sure how to do exactly what you want in one SQL query.